# encrypt password from a database in mongo

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing a mean stack app and I have one username and password in the database that I hardcoded. I want to encrypt that password and store it back in the DB. 
(using mongoDB, AngularJS, nodeJS)
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using angularjs and node you can use mongoose(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) from npm to map your data. Then you can use bcrypt(https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to store your passwords safely.

bcrypt also has salt so you can look into that if you want to prevent bruteforcing.

```html
var mg = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var SALT_FACTOR = 10;
mg.connect('mongodb://localhost');

var db = mg.connection;

db.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('error', err);
});

db.once('open', function(){
  console.log('Connection successful');
});

var Schema = mg.Schema;
var mySchema = new Schema({
  name:String,
  password:String
});

var User = mg.model('User', mySchema);

mySchema.pre('save', function(next){
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, function(err, salt){
    if(err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
      if(err) return next(err);

      user.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});

var testdata = new  User({
  name: "root",
  password: "123456"
});

testdata.save(function(err, data){
  if(err) console.log(err);
  else console.log ('WOHOO:' , data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not called encryption but hashing. You can use `bcrypt` module in nodejs for that. In order to hash the password

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
bcrypt.hash(passwordFromSignup, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  // store hash in database
});
```

And in order to verify the user password

```
bcrypt.compare(passwordFromLogin, hashFromDatabase, function(err, res) {
    // res evaluates to `true` if successfull login
});
```